# Serializing inner delegate classes - Class is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of

Tags: kotlin

I have a Product class, which also contains SubProducts.
A certain service builds a delegate class that "wraps" them in order to include some metadata.
However, when I return the data to the client, I only need to return the "pure" Product+SubProducts entities.

```
@Serializable(with = ProductSerializer::class)
interface Product {
    val title: String
    val price: String
    val supplier: ProductSupplier
    val expiresAt: LocalDateTime
    
    val subProducts: List<SubProduct>
}

class X: Product { ... }
class Y: Product { ... }

@Serializable(with = SubProductSerializer::class)
interface SubProduct {
    val title: String
    val price: String
}

class Z: SubProduct { ... }
class W: SubProduct { ... }
```

And the delegates :

```
class ProductBill(
    val product: Product,
    @Transient
    val supplierTaxAmount: String,
    @Transient
    val metadata: String,
): Product by product

class SubProductBill(
    val subProduct: SubProduct,
    @Transient
    val supplierTaxAmount: String,
    @Transient
    val metadata: String,
): SubProduct by subProduct
```

Now, a certain service builds for me a ProductBill which can contain SubProductBills.
What I want to return to the Client in REST API, is only the Product (which can contain SubProducts)

It seems to work when there's no subproducts.
But when there are sub products, I get this :

`Class 'SubProductBill' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'SubProduct'.`